# Application logging in Xamarin

Tags: logging, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm new to Android development and interested in some best practices. What do I use for logging in my application:

- `System.Diagnostics` (framework-level API? where is `System.Diagnostics.Trace` then?)
- `Android.Util.Log` (OS-level API?)
- `Console.WriteLine()` (what is console on Android device?)
- external libraries like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Comment: This is really a terrific question; wish it would have stayed open.  I'm wrestling with the same issue right now.

Comment: Best practice and code poc would have been interesting to see. Too me it looks like a good question. I can not see how the moderator came to his conclusion.

Comment: Please reopen this question. It is constructive and he is asking for the best practice, not oppinion.